# Output in threads are not in order

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        NewThread ob1 = new NewThread("One");
        NewThread ob2 = new NewThread("Two");
        NewThread ob3 = new NewThread("Three");

        try{
            System.out.println("Waiting for threads to finish.");
            ob1.t.join();
            ob2.t.join();
            ob3.t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Main thread interrupted");
        }

        System.out.println("Exiting main thread.");
    }
}
class NewThread implements Runnable {
    Thread t;

    NewThread(String name){
        t = new Thread(this, name);
        System.out.println("New thread: " + t);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run(){
        try{
            for(int i=3; i>0; i--){
                System.out.println(t.getName() + ": " + i);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " interrupted.");
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting " + t.getName());
    }
}
```

The code above was intended to give this output:

*New thread: Thread[One,5,main]

New thread: Thread[Two,5,main]

New thread: Thread[Three,5,main]

Waiting for threads to finish.

One: 3

Two: 3

Three: 3

One: 2

Two: 2

Three: 2

One: 1

Two: 1

Three: 1

Exiting One

Exiting Two

Exiting Three

Exiting main thread.*

Instead it is giving output as follows:

*New thread: Thread[One,5,main]

New thread: Thread[Two,5,main]

One: 3

New thread: Thread[Three,5,main]

Two: 3

Waiting for threads to finish.

Three: 3

Three: 2

One: 2

Two: 2

Three: 1

Two: 1

One: 1

Exiting Two

Exiting Three

Exiting One

Exiting main thread.*

Please help me to correct the code.

Comment: Why do you expect them to be in that order?  Isn't the whole point of starting multiple threads that they can proceed with their work asynchronously?

Comment: Ditto that:  If you want a sequence of events to happen in a particular order, write code to do them in that order in a single thread.  Every multi-threaded program needs _some_ synchronization between threads, but the more synchronization you use, the less benefit you will get from the multiple threads.  The real challenge in multi-threaded programming is to imagine a solution to your problem that does _not_ depend on tight coupling between the threads.

Comment: P.S.; `Thread.sleep(t)` is OK for demos and experiments, but you should never rely on it as a means to synchronize threads.  The timeout argument `t` is only a lower bound on how long the call actually will take, and on a loaded system, the actual sleep time can be unpredictable.  `Thread.sleep()` is a primitive operation that is meant to be used in a higher level class (e.g., ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) for scheduling periodic events, delayed events, alarms, etc.

Comment: It would help if you explained why you think this is a problem. For example, what do you think makes it so that `Exiting One` must be printed before `Exiting Two`? Where does the code reflect this intent?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing multithreading, there is no guarantee what order threads will run without giving a thread a higher priority over another. Just because your want your output to be in a certain order, IMO, defeats the purpose of multithreading. You may as well not have spawned a threads to begin with.  For "true" multithreading, I would expect your outputs to be mingled like you are showing, but again that is not guaranteed.