# Why is the program execution isn't as expected

Tags: java, multithreading

Thread two is running first on output though I've called start() method of thread1 at first. Why this is happening? 
Output:
Thread two running: 0
Thread two running: 1
Thread one running: 0
Thread two running: 2
....

```
package interfacetest;

class thread1 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Thread one running: " +i);
            }
    }
}
class thread2 extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        for(int j=0; j<10; j ++) {
            System.out.println("Thread two running: " +j);
            }
    }
 }

class InterfaceTest {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    thread1 t1 = new thread1();
    thread2 t2=  new thread2();
    t1.start();
    t2.start(); 
   }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29610453/10058326 answer already here

Comment: Could you be clearer about what you expect to see? And it would be easier on the eyes if you formatted the output you were seeing.  But I'd suggest you need to find a way to allow the main thread to wait until the background threads have completed, which probably explains why they're stopping after only 2 iterations.

Comment: The OS scheduler decides which threads runs how long and when they get paused. It is free to pause the thread at any time and do a context switch. So the order in which your threads are executed is unknown and can be completely mixed. A couple of seconds for the first thread, a hour for the second, a minute for the first again, ... The scheduler tries to be fair of course, but it has a lot of freedom.

Comment: Also see [Order of thread execution in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234138/order-of-thread-execution-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

When we start thread, java starts execution of run method in separate thread. And thread ordering is never gauranteed. Here as you are simply starting 2 different threads no gaurantee that they will be executed in sequence.